# Extracting coefficients from equation

Tags: polynomials, algebraic-manipulation

I am looking for a Mathematica code that finds the coefficients from an equation. So for example, when I have the equation $ax^2+bx+c$ I want to the code to spit out: `{a,b,c}`. Is there a quick way to do that? Thanks for any advice and help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
CoefficientList[a*x^2 + b*x + c, x] // Reverse
(* {a, b, c} *)
```